# Adding a class to check_box_tag in contact form (mailer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, actionmailer, form-helpers

I have a contact form with a checkbox asking for consent to send emails to the user - as in each field has a key feeding back to the site owner. I'm trying to add a class to the checkbox itself `input-consent`, but when I try the following:

```
<%= check_box_tag(:consent, class: "input-consent") %>
```

I get this error:

```
app/views/registrations/new.html.erb:56: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'.
```

How should I be composing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try with this?

```
<%= check_box_tag :consent, 1, false, class: 'input-consent' %>
```

[Refer to check_box_tag here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag)